# C# : Comparer Int List (Element origin position)

Tags: c#, list, compare

I compare items per day but my days are identical.
I have a list, for example:

- Item 1: Day 1
- Item 2: Day 1
- Item 3: Day 1
- Item 4: Day 1
- Item 5: Day 1
- Item 6: Day 1
- Item 7: Day 1
- Item 8: Day 1

My comparer : I compare it a day

`public class byDay : Comparer<int>
{
public override int Compare(int day1, int day2)
            {

                if (day2 - day1 > 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (day2 - day1 < 0)
                {
                    return 1;
                }

return 0;
}`

And in the end my list is not in the same order every day and yet are identical.

- Item 1: Day 1
- Item 6: Day 1
- Item 3: Day 1
- Item 7: Day 1
- Item 8: Day 1
- Item 2: Day 1
- Item 4: Day 1
- Item 5: Day 1

I note that the "comparer" not necessarily compare the next object. For example: Item 1 with Item 2 but Item 1 with Item 4.

So my list normally should not change but remained in the original order for the days are identical.

The "return 0" should not change the position of the element in the list ???

Comment: My problem: Positioning of elements in the list. Every day is the same on my list. The return 0 does not leave the object in its original position in the list.

Comment: Do use List.Sort() Method?

Comment: yes, I use "myList.Sort(new byDay());" except that my list is not returned in the same order as the original but yet all my days are identical.

I would only have my list in the same order if I have a single day.

Comment: List<T>.Sort is an unstable sort. You can see detail here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok thank you, you have a solution to this problem. Or is it that I use the Spell merge proposed by Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: I used OrderBy: myList = myList.OrderBy(item => item, new byDay()).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

The *origin* of misbehaviour is that the default sorting algorithm (QuickSort) is not a *stable* one. Possible *Linq* solution (by-way) is to sort by index:

```
  // TODO: put the actual type here
  List<DateTime> source = ....

  List<DateTime> result = source
   .Select(item, index => new { // <- data itself + index
      item = item,
      index = index 
     })
   .OrderBy(data => data.item) // <- by day, date, etc.
   .ThenBy(data => data.index) // <- on tie by index
   .Select(data => data.item)  // <- return to original type
   .ToList();
```

Drawback: a new list istance (`result`) is created. If you want *to sort out* the existing list, you have to implement any *stable sorting* algorithm (other than QuickSort), e.g. *Merge sort*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort